# Vue draggable constrain height

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuedraggable

I am implementing a drag-and-drop with vue-draggable: https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable.

Is there a way to constrain the height of the element when dragging it? Otherwise it looks quite odd whenever doing a drag event when the section literally expands outside the browser itself.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Vue.Draggable is based on and offering all features of [Sortable.js](https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable).

As you can see in the documentation, the dragging item has by default the class "sortable-drag", so in your CSS you can use this class to give him some style (including height property).

Here is an example, take a look at the drag component:

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-draggable-example-jhtyf

Comment: thanks, but how is th example relevant, it looks like these are row-based blocks rather than something like a column-based item? Is it possible to show an example more similar to a table like in the query?

Answer (score 0):

You can also apply the `chosen-class` and set your class to constrain the height that way! Hope that helps.

https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable#chosenclass-option

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33301593)